# Does Json.Net (Newtownsoft) support # "link" resolution?

Tags: json, json.net, json-deserialization

Is there native support for or an obvious extension point for handling the following scenario?

### JSON

```
{
  "big": {
    "config": {
      "goes": {
        "deep": "#/another/value"
      }
    }
  },
  "another": {
    "value": [
       "18.4",
       "99.63"
    ]
  }
}
```

### POCO

```
public class MyPoco
{
   public BigPoco Big { get; set; }
   public AnotherPoco Another { get; set; }
}

public class BigPoco { public ConfigPoco Config { get; set; }  }
public class ConfigPoco { public GoesPoco Goes { get; set; }  }

public class GoesPoco
{
   public List<decimal> Deep { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherPoco
{
   public List<decimal> Value { get; set; }
}
```

I like it and VS suggested it with Intellisense, using the `#/path/to/key` format, but I don't know what to call it so I don't know how to begin to search for it.

And... even though I could write a rudimentary version using reflection, I'd rather use what is available or an extension point that makes sense.

Comment: No, there is no native support for the link syntax you describe.  But you could parse the JSON to a `JObject` and then use a recursive algorithm to resolve the links before converting it to your POCO structure.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. But I was hoping to avoid the work

Comment: @BrianRogers what about an extension point for Json.Net? Is there a logical place to begin other than just writing a new serializer?

Comment: The main extension point for Json.Net is the `JsonConverter`, which allows you to handle how a particular object type is serialized or deserialized.  However, I'm not sure it will help you much here since (1) you want the link resolution to happen across ALL your object types and (2) your links may be forward references (the link refers to something that comes *later* in the JSON), per the example you posted in your question.  That means you'll need to deserialize the entire JSON before you can even begin to resolve the references.

Comment: Another extension point is the `ContractResolver` which allows you to programmatically apply certain behaviors to a wide set of object types (the canonical example is camel casing all property names during serialization).  You can also use a resolver to attach an `IValueProvider` to object properties, which allows you to change what value is be read or written for that property.  It doesn't have direct access to the `JsonReader` or `JsonWriter` like a converter does though.